# nftables dnat map rule failing silently

Tags: nat, nftables, netfilter

I'm working from the answer of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/745265/nftables-dnat-with-source-address-restriction-and-just-one-map) question and `man nft` in order to create some `dnat` rules in my `nftables` config.

The relevant config extract is:

```
define src_ip       = 192.168.1.128/26
define dst_ip       = 192.168.1.1
define docker_dns   = 172.20.10.5

table inet nat {
    map dns_nat {
        type ipv4_addr . ipv4_addr . ip_proto . inet_service : ipv4_addr . inet_service
        flags interval
        elements = {
            $src_ip . $dst_ip . udp . 53 : $docker_dns . 5353,
        }
    }
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept;
        
        dnat to ip saddr . ip daddr . ip protocol . th dport map @dns_nat;
    }
}
```

When I apply this rule with `nft -f`, I see no command output so I presume it's succeeded. However when I inspect the ruleset using `nft list ruleset` the rules aren't present. When the `dnat to ...` line is commented out the rules appear to be applied, however when the line is present the rules are not applied.

The collection of rules in the `prerouting` chain I'm attempting to replace is:

```
ip saddr $src_ip ip daddr $dst_ip udp dport 53 dnat to $docker_dns:5353;
...
```

Version information:

```
# nft -v
nftables v1.0.6 (Lester Gooch #5)
# uname -r
6.1.0-11-amd64
```

Why might this not be working? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems.

- no error is displayed

  This looks to be a bug in *nftables* 1.0.6, see following bullets.

  Here with the same version and OP's ruleset in `/tmp/ruleset.nft`:

  ```shell
  # nft -V
  nftables v1.0.6 (Lester Gooch #5)
  [...]
  # nft -f /tmp/ruleset.nft 
  /tmp/ruleset.nft:7:38-45: Error: unknown datatype ip_proto
          type ipv4_addr . ipv4_addr . ip_proto . inet_service : ipv4_addr . inet_service
                                       ^^^^^^^^
  /tmp/ruleset.nft:6:9-15: Error: set definition does not specify key
      map dns_nat {
          ^^^^^^^
  ```
- Error: unknown datatype `ip_proto`

  The original linked Q/A used the correct type `inet_proto`. This should not have been replaced with `ip_proto` which is an unknown type. So replace back:

  > ```
  > type ipv4_addr . ipv4_addr . ip_proto . inet_service : ipv4_addr . inet_service
  > ```

  with the correct original spelling:

  ```
  type ipv4_addr . ipv4_addr . inet_proto . inet_service : ipv4_addr . inet_service
  ```

  A list of available types can be found in `nft(8)` at [PAYLOAD EXPRESSION](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#PAYLOAD_EXPRESSIONS) and more precisely for this case at [IPV4 HEADER EXPRESSION](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#IPV4_HEADER_EXPRESSION):

  > | Keyword | Description | Type |
  > | --- | --- | --- |
  > | [...] |  |  |
  > | `protocol` | Upper layer protocol | `inet_proto` |
  > | [...] |  |  |

  `typeof ip protocol` <=> `type inet_proto` (not `type ip_proto`).

  Normally `typeof` should be preferred to `type` to avoid having to guess the correct type, but [as I wrote in the linked Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/745265/nftables-dnat-with-source-address-restriction-and-just-one-map/745271#745271), some versions of *nftables* might not cope correctly with this precise case. The replacement would have been:

  ```
  typeof ip saddr . ip daddr . ip protocol . th dport : ip daddr . th dport
  ```

  which is almost a cut/paste from the rule using it, but its behavior should be thoroughly tested.
- no error is displayed - take 2

  Once this previous error is fixed (and the result put in `/tmp/ruleset2.nft`), then, as OP wrote, trying again the ruleset fails silently:

  ```shell
  # nft -V
  nftables v1.0.6 (Lester Gooch #5)
    cli:        editline
    json:       yes
    minigmp:    no
    libxtables: yes
  # nft -f /tmp/ruleset2.nft
  # echo $?
  1
  #
  ```

  The only clue it failed is non-0 return code.

  While with a newer *nftables* version:

  ```shell
  # nft -V
  nftables v1.0.8 (Old Doc Yak #2)
    cli:        editline
    json:       yes
    minigmp:    no
    libxtables: yes
  # nft -f /tmp/ruleset2.nft 
  /tmp/ruleset2.nft:16:9-12: Error: specify `dnat ip' or 'dnat ip6' in inet table to disambiguate
          dnat to ip saddr . ip daddr . ip protocol . th dport map @dns_nat;
          ^^^^
  #
  ```

  Now the error is displayed. Whatever was the issue in 1.0.6 it has been fixed at least with version 1.0.8.
- Error: specify `dnat ip' or 'dnat ip6' in inet table to disambiguate

  Because NAT is done in the `inet` family (combined IPv4+IPv6) rather than either `ip` (IPv4) or `ip6` (IPv6) family, one parameter which is usually optional becomes mandatory: state the IP version NAT should be applied to  (even if one could infer it from the map table layout (IPv4)). Documentation tells:

  > [NAT STATEMENTS](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#NAT_STATEMENTS)
  >
  > ```
  > snat [[ip | ip6] to] ADDR_SPEC [:PORT_SPEC] [FLAGS]
  > dnat [[ip | ip6] to] ADDR_SPEC [:PORT_SPEC] [FLAGS]
  > masquerade [to :PORT_SPEC] [FLAGS]
  > redirect [to :PORT_SPEC] [FLAGS]
  > ```
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > **When used in the inet family** (available with kernel 5.2), **the dnat and
  > snat statements require the use of the ip and ip6 keyword** in case an
  > address is provided, see the examples below.

  So:

  > ```
  > dnat to ip saddr . ip daddr . ip protocol . th dport map @dns_nat;
  > ```

  should be replaced with:

  ```
  dnat ip to ip saddr . ip daddr . ip protocol . th dport map @dns_nat
  ```

  The original Q/A didn't state the family, so it would be assumed it was the default `ip` family which wouldn't require this.

  Of course, this will work with *nftables* 1.0.6, only the error reporting had a problem. The return code will now be 0.

Comment: Ah sorry the `ip_proto` was a stupid typo from me when writing the question >.<! Thanks, the `dnat ip` change has fixed it. Hopefully there aren't many other bugs like this